# "argument is of length zero" error in RandomForest tuneRF()

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I used this code,

```
tuneRF(x = mtry[,c(4:18)],
   y = mtry$Os, ntreeTry=50, stepFactor=2, 
   improve=0.05,trace=TRUE, plot=TRUE, doBest=FALSE)
```

And got the error:

> Error in if (errorOld < 0) stop("Initial setting gave 0 error and no room for improvement.") :
>    argument is of length zero

What should I change?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: is your dataset called mtry??

Comment: yes. I prepared on dataset that it's  80% of total data. ans os is one column that I want to predict it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when my I accidentally typed a column that didn't exist for the response column.  Perhaps your `mtry$Os` column does not exist (it's hard to solve your problem w/o a reproducible example).

Example:

```
> library(randomForest)
> data("iris")
> tuneRF(x = iris[1:4,], y = iris$notacol)
Error in if (errorOld < 0) stop("Initial setting gave 0 error and no room for improvement.") : 
  argument is of length zero
```